# 1073.75 MB of file backed memory dirtied over 186 seconds (5770.75 KB per second average), exceeding limit of 12.43 KB per second over 86400 seconds

Tags: ios, crash

iOS crash

Look the crash stack, is it the icloud backup get something error? I don't know what is this error.

Help, thanks.

```
1073.75 MB of file backed memory dirtied over 186 seconds (5770.75 KB per second average), exceeding limit of 12.43 KB per second over 86400 seconds
```

```
Command:          HelloTalk_Binary
Path:             
Identifier:       
Version:          3.6.4 (6)
Beta Identifier:  5D4C1274-7310-4015-9227-B2190563BAE3
PID:              623

Event:            disk writes
Action taken:     none
Writes:           1073.75 MB of file backed memory dirtied over 186 seconds (5770.75 KB per second average), exceeding limit of 12.43 KB per second over 86400 seconds
Writes limit:     1073.74 MB
Limit duration:   86400s
Writes caused:    1073.75 MB
Writes duration:  186s
Duration:         186.07s
Duration Sampled: 45.98s
Steps:            60 ( (10.49 MB/step))

Hardware model:   iPhone10,3
Active cpus:      6


Heaviest stack for the target process:
  60  ??? (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 48008) [0x18271eb88]
  60  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 275516) [0x1826b643c]
  60  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 237864) [0x1826ad128]
  60  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 235280) [0x1826ac710]
  60  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 377220) [0x1826cf184]
  60  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 374288) [0x1826ce610]
  57  ??? (HelloTalk_Binary + 23667476) [0x105792314]
  23  ??? (HelloTalk_Binary + 23665404) [0x105791afc]
  23  ??? (HelloTalk_Binary + 32163208) [0x105fac588]
  23  ??? (<7F66DDA9-9EB4-3CA9-94BF-2E87E9B8B20C> + 47812) [0x108cffac4]
  23  ??? (<7F66DDA9-9EB4-3CA9-94BF-2E87E9B8B20C> + 48280) [0x108cffc98]
  23  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 245252) [0x182631e04]
  20  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 244268) [0x182631a2c]
  20  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 5588) [0x1825f75d4]
  20  ??? (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 154316) [0x1827faacc]


Powerstats for:   [623]
Bundle ID:        
Adam ID:          0
Is first party:   No
App version:      3.6.4
Build version:    6
Is Beta:          No
Share with Devs:  Yes
UUID:             8A9B6AAB-F4F1-3ADA-9CDF-0C0D23A46AF1
Path:             
Architecture:     arm64
Footprint:        217.66 MB -> 171.48 MB (-46.17 MB) (max 362.86 MB )
Pageins:          399 pages
Start time:       2019-11-28 08:58:06 +0800
End time:         2019-11-28 08:58:52 +0800
Num samples:      60 (100%)
CPU Time:         13.931s
Primary state:    59 samples Frontmost App, Non-Suppressed, Kernel mode, Effective Thread QoS User Initiated, Requested Thread QoS User Initiated, Override Thread QoS Unspecified
User Activity:    0 samples Idle, 60 samples Active
Power Source:     60 samples on Battery, 0 samples on AC
  60  ??? (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 48008) [0x18271eb88]
    60  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 275516) [0x1826b643c]
      60  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 237864) [0x1826ad128]
        60  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 235280) [0x1826ac710]
          60  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 377220) [0x1826cf184]
            60  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 374288) [0x1826ce610]
              57  __31-[HTBackupToIcloudModel backup]_block_invoke (HTBackupToIcloudModel.m:358 in HelloTalk_Binary + 23667476) [0x105792314]
                23  -[HTBackupToIcloudModel createBackupFile] (HTBackupToIcloudModel.m:271 in HelloTalk_Binary + 23665404) [0x105791afc]
                  23  -[ZipWriteStream writeData:] (ZipWriteStream.m:53 in HelloTalk_Binary + 32163208) [0x105fac588]
                    23  zipWriteInFileInZip (zip.c:1464 in SSZipArchive + 47812) [0x108cffac4]
                      23  zip64FlushWriteBuffer (zip.c:1381 in SSZipArchive + 48280) [0x108cffc98]
                        23  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 245252) [0x182631e04]
                          20  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 244268) [0x182631a2c]
                            20  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 5588) [0x1825f75d4]
                              20  ??? (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 154316) [0x1827faacc]
                          3   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 244316) [0x182631a5c]
                            3   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 235260) [0x18262f6fc]
                              3   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 5588) [0x1825f75d4]
                                3   ??? (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 154316) [0x1827faacc]
                20  -[HTBackupToIcloudModel createBackupFile] (HTBackupToIcloudModel.m:272 in HelloTalk_Binary + 23665416) [0x105791b08]
                  20  -[ZipWriteStream finishedWriting] (ZipWriteStream.m:61 in HelloTalk_Binary + 32163424) [0x105fac660]
                    18  zipCloseFileInZipRaw64 (zip.c:1589 in SSZipArchive + 48540) [0x108cffd9c]
                      18  zip64FlushWriteBuffer (zip.c:1381 in SSZipArchive + 48280) [0x108cffc98]
                        18  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 245252) [0x182631e04]
                          18  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 244268) [0x182631a2c]
                            18  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 5588) [0x1825f75d4]
                              18  ??? (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 154316) [0x1827faacc]
                    2   zipCloseFileInZipRaw64 (zip.c:1718 in SSZipArchive + 49524) [0x108d00174]
                      2   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 5144) [0x1825f7418]
                        2   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 243516) [0x18263173c]
                          2   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 235260) [0x18262f6fc]
                            2   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 5588) [0x1825f75d4]
                              2   ??? (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 154316) [0x1827faacc]
                13  -[HTBackupToIcloudModel createBackupFile] (HTBackupToIcloudModel.m:252 in HelloTalk_Binary + 23664864) [0x1057918e0]
                  13  -[ZipWriteStream writeData:] (ZipWriteStream.m:53 in HelloTalk_Binary + 32163208) [0x105fac588]
                    13  zipWriteInFileInZip (zip.c:1464 in SSZipArchive + 47812) [0x108cffac4]
                      13  zip64FlushWriteBuffer (zip.c:1381 in SSZipArchive + 48280) [0x108cffc98]
                        13  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 245252) [0x182631e04]
                          13  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 244268) [0x182631a2c]
                            13  ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 5588) [0x1825f75d4]
                              13  ??? (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 154316) [0x1827faacc]
                1   -[HTBackupToIcloudModel createBackupFile] (HTBackupToIcloudModel.m:253 in HelloTalk_Binary + 23664876) [0x1057918ec]
                  1   -[ZipWriteStream finishedWriting] (ZipWriteStream.m:61 in HelloTalk_Binary + 32163424) [0x105fac660]
                    1   zipCloseFileInZipRaw64 (zip.c:1589 in SSZipArchive + 48540) [0x108cffd9c]
                      1   zip64FlushWriteBuffer (zip.c:1381 in SSZipArchive + 48280) [0x108cffc98]
                        1   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 245252) [0x182631e04]
                          1   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 244268) [0x182631a2c]
                            1   ??? (libsystem_c.dylib + 5588) [0x1825f75d4]
                              1   ??? (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 154316) [0x1827faacc]
              2   __25-[HTCache synchronizeNow]_block_invoke (HTCache.m:555 in HelloTalk_Binary + 28087512) [0x105bc94d8]
                2   ??? (Foundation + 424364) [0x182d1a9ac]
                  2   ??? (Foundation + 1163316) [0x182dcf034]
                    2   ??? (Foundation + 297596) [0x182cfba7c]
                      2   ??? (Foundation + 1164516) [0x182dcf4e4]
                        2   ??? (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 162716) [0x1827fcb9c]
                          1   <Effective Thread QoS User Interactive>
              1   __53-[SensorsAnalyticsSDK track:withProperties:withType:]_block_invoke (SensorsAnalyticsSDK.m:1668 in SensorsAnalyticsSDK + 194464) [0x108d477a0]
                1   -[SensorsAnalyticsSDK enqueueWithType:andEvent:] (SensorsAnalyticsSDK.m:1404 in SensorsAnalyticsSDK + 187712) [0x108d45d40]
                  1   -[MessageQueueBySqlite addObejct:withType:] (MessageQueueBySqlite.m:115 in SensorsAnalyticsSDK + 31508) [0x108d1fb14]
                    1   ??? (libsqlite3.dylib + 269148) [0x18465ab5c]
                      1   ??? (libsqlite3.dylib + 313648) [0x184665930]
                        1   ??? (libsqlite3.dylib + 440088) [0x184684718]
                          1   ??? (libsqlite3.dylib + 437700) [0x184683dc4]
                            1   ??? (libsqlite3.dylib + 427668) [0x184681694]
                              1   ??? (libsqlite3.dylib + 483304) [0x18468efe8]
                                1   ??? (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 157916) [0x1827fb8dc]
```

```
- (BOOL)createBackupFile {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = NSFileManager.new;

        // 创建缓存路径
        NSString *tmpICloudPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iCloud"];
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:tmpICloudPath isDirectory:NULL]) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:tmpICloudPath error:NULL];
        }
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:tmpICloudPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:NULL error:NULL];

        NSString *zipFilePath = [tmpICloudPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Backup.zip"];
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:zipFilePath]) {
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:zipFilePath error:NULL];
        }

        ZipFile *zipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:zipFilePath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];

        // 开始压缩
        NSInteger totalFileCounts = 0;

        // 压缩数据库
        NSString *dbBackupPath = nil;
        NSArray *dbSubpaths = nil;
        @autoreleasepool {
            dbBackupPath = [HTPath localBackupPathWithUserId:[[HTCache sharedCache] stringForKey:HT_UserId]];
            dbSubpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:dbBackupPath];
            totalFileCounts += dbSubpaths.count;
        }

        // 压缩语音
        NSString *audioPath = nil;
        NSArray *audioSubpaths = nil;
        @autoreleasepool {
            audioPath = [HTPath localAudioPathWithUserId:[[HTCache sharedCache] stringForKey:HT_UserId]];
            audioSubpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:audioPath];
            totalFileCounts += audioSubpaths.count;
        }

        // 压缩图片
        NSString *imagesPath = nil;
        NSMutableArray *imageSubpaths = nil;
        @autoreleasepool {
            imagesPath = [HTPath localImagePathWithUserId:[[HTCache sharedCache] stringForKey:HT_UserId]];
            NSArray *tempImagesSubPath = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:imagesPath];
            imageSubpaths = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (NSString *path in tempImagesSubPath) {
                if ([path hasSuffix:@"_thum.jpg"]) {
                    [imageSubpaths addObject:path];
                }
            }

            totalFileCounts += imageSubpaths.count;
        }

        // 压缩视频缩略图，不压缩视频文件
        NSString *videosPath = nil;
        NSMutableArray *videoSubpaths = nil;
        @autoreleasepool {
            videosPath = [HTPath localVideoPathWithUserId:[[HTCache sharedCache] stringForKey:HT_UserId]];
            NSArray *tempVideoSubpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:videosPath];
            videoSubpaths = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (NSString *path in tempVideoSubpaths) {
                if([path hasSuffix:@"_thum.jpg"]) {
                    [videoSubpaths addObject:path];
                }
            }

            totalFileCounts += videoSubpaths.count;
        }

        float onePercent = 1 / (float)totalFileCounts;
        float tempTotalPercent = self.conpressProgress / 100.0f;

        NSLog(@"iCloud total files: %@", @(totalFileCounts).stringValue);

        BOOL isDir = YES;
        for(NSString *path in dbSubpaths){
            @autoreleasepool {
                NSString *fullPath = [dbBackupPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
                if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir){
                    ZipWriteStream *stream= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Backup/Backup/%@", path] compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelFastest];
                    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath options:NSDataReadingUncached error:NULL];
                    [stream writeData:data];
                    [stream finishedWriting];
                }
            }

            tempTotalPercent += onePercent;
            int conpressProgress = tempTotalPercent * 100;
            if (conpressProgress != self.conpressProgress) {
                self.conpressProgress = conpressProgress;
            }
        }


        for(NSString *path in audioSubpaths){
            @autoreleasepool {
                NSString *fullPath = [audioPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
                if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir){
                    ZipWriteStream *stream= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Backup/audios/%@", path] compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelNone];
                    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath options:NSDataReadingUncached error:NULL];
                    [stream writeData:data];
                    [stream finishedWriting];
                }
            }

            tempTotalPercent += onePercent;
            int conpressProgress = tempTotalPercent * 100;
            if (conpressProgress != self.conpressProgress) {
                self.conpressProgress = conpressProgress;
            }
        }


        for(NSString *path in imageSubpaths){
            @autoreleasepool {
                NSString *fullPath = [imagesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
                if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir){
                    ZipWriteStream *stream= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Backup/images/%@", path] compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelNone];
                    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath options:NSDataReadingUncached error:NULL];
                    [stream writeData:data];
                    [stream finishedWriting];
                }
            }

            tempTotalPercent += onePercent;
            int conpressProgress = tempTotalPercent * 100;
            if (conpressProgress != self.conpressProgress) {
                self.conpressProgress = conpressProgress;
            }
        }


        for(NSString *path in videoSubpaths){
            @autoreleasepool {
                NSString *fullPath = [videosPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
                if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir){
                    ZipWriteStream *stream= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Backup/videos/%@", path] compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelFastest];
                    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath options:NSDataReadingUncached error:NULL];
                    [stream writeData:data];
                    [stream finishedWriting];
                }
            }

            tempTotalPercent += onePercent;
            int conpressProgress = tempTotalPercent * 100;
            if (conpressProgress != self.conpressProgress) {
                self.conpressProgress = conpressProgress;
            }
        }

        [zipFile close];
        [zipFile release];

        NSLog(@"conpress end");

        NSDictionary *attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:zipFilePath error:NULL];
        self.backupSize = [attributes doubleForKey:NSFileSize] / (1024.0f * 1024.0f);

        return YES;
    }

}
```

Comment: did you fix it? I am with almost the same problem, but it's on database operation

Comment: Just wondering if you were able to track this down? I am getting the same crash, but I can't figure out where it is coming from.

Comment: Do you have any update for this? I got the same problem.

Comment: Same issue here.  Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: We have same problem. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Also running into this, and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on this error

Comment: Same issue... most likely having something to do with a sqlite db... did anybody ever find a reason?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a general limitation on macOS/iOS which enforce a strict <1GB of file writes per 24 hour period, on SSDs. Exceeding this limit triggers a warning.
If you see "Action: none" in the logs, then it doesn't crash, it's just a warning (which can slow things down a bit while it collects backtraces). Maybe there are other actions, such as crashing the process, don't know.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing-disk-writes#Eliminate-excessive-write-operations

There doesn't seem to be a way to disable this.